# Java scrollpane not adding to panel instead displaying white screen

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

So I have a table that is displaying data from a `database` but since there's a lot of data being outputted into the table it goes way beyond the `bounds` I have set for the JFrame.

I've tried adding a ScrollPane below but instead of allowing me to `scroll down the GUI` it will display white over the whole `GUI`! All I need to do is make it so I can scroll down to view the whole table!

Here is my code:

```
public class ViewAll extends JFrame{
    //Jtextfields, buttons, labels
    private static JButton one = new JButton("Back");
    private static JLabel lblMembTitle = new JLabel("<html><h1>All Members</h1></html>");
    private static JLabel lblPlayTitle = new JLabel("<html><h1>All Playlists</h1><br /></html>");
    //Containers, Panels, Scrollpanes
    private Container mainCon = this.getContentPane();
    private static JPanel pnlTable = new JPanel();


    //Tables
    private static JTable tblShowAllMemb = new JTable();
    private static JTable tblShowAllPlay = new JTable();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(pnlTable,   ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);



    public ViewAll(){
        super("Search/Edit/Delete Members");
        this.setBounds(400, 800, 854,400);
        //Add panel and create table model
        mainCon.add(pnlTable);
        MemTableModel tblMembers = new MemTableModel();
        PlayTableModel tblPlaylist = new PlayTableModel();
        this.add(scrollPane);

        //Add table and set tableModel
        pnlTable.add(lblMembTitle);
        pnlTable.add(tblShowAllMemb);
        tblShowAllMemb.setModel(tblMembers);

        pnlTable.add(lblPlayTitle);
        pnlTable.add(tblShowAllPlay);
        tblShowAllPlay.setModel(tblPlaylist);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you add your `JPanel pnlTable` to multiple containers, first to `scrollPane`, then to `Container mainCon` (so it is not in `scrollPane`, as a component can be only in one container). So when you add `scrollPane` separetly to `ViewAll` it display nothing, because it is empty.

So use:

```
mainCon.add(scrollPane);
```

or delete `mainCon.add(pnlTable);` and use only:

```
this.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: I've done this and it works but for some reason it will place both the tables and `Jlabels` horizontally? So instead of scrolling down you have to scroll horizontally!!??

Comment: @James111 try to change layout of `pnlTable`, default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` and propably it couse problem. change it on for example `BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS`

Comment: Yeah your right...I haven't done much work with the Layout managers. I probably should spend more time on the layouts as I haven't styled any of my GUI's!